# Inputting data to a blank access table, from MS excel

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have some VBA code that creates a new blank table, What I want to do is import a excel table, taking the first row as field names then import the rest of the sheet as values in my fields.

Do I need to have predefined the field names for this to work?

```
Private Sub Command11_Click()
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = OpenFile()

    'Create Temp Table
    DoCmd.RunSQL ("CREATE TABLE Temp_Import_Table")
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Temp_Import_Table", FilePath, False


    DoCmd.RunSQL ("DROP TABLE Temp_Import_table")

    MsgBox (FilePath)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create the table schema beforehand, TransferSpreadsheet will create the table for you if it doesn't exist already.  If you specify HasFieldNames to True, the field names from Excel will get imported as field headers.  If you want, you can just just check for table existence before running TransferSpreadsheet and delete it if it exists.

If you really want the table to exist prior, you can do transfer the spreadsheet once without deleting it and keep that table schema.  If you don't delete it in code, it will be persistent and subsequent calls to TransferSpreadsheet (assuming the data fits into that structure) should append data to that table.  In this case, you would need to clear out the data in the table first.

Answer (score 0):

The TransferSpreadSheet command has a parameter HasFieldName. If that is set to true the first row will be used as fieldnames

see here [MSDN, VBA TransferSpreadSheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff844793%28v=office.15%29.aspx), or click on the first topic at google, searching transferspreadsheet, or hit F1 when in VBAEditor on the word transferSreadSheet

Comment: I've already tried this, the issue is that i have no fields at-all, so i just get the error "FirstName doesn't exist in destination table"